# Cannot run rancher UI using docker

Tags: docker, rancher

I user command line `docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped \ -p 80:80 -p 443:443 \ --privileged \ rancher/rancher:latest`
The container still run but I cannot access Rancher UI

```
8e95a158842c   rancher/rancher:latest   "entrypoint.sh"   45 minutes ago   Up 7 seconds   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp   relaxed_chandrasekhar
```

Then t run `docker logs 8e95a158842c`

```
2021-11-04 22:25:56.455037 W | pkg/fileutil: check file permission: directory "management-state/etcd" exist, but the permission is "drwxr-xr-x". The recommended permission is "-rwx------" to prevent possible unprivileged access to the data.
2021-11-04 22:25:56.543162 I | etcdserver: restarting member 8e9e05c52164694d in cluster cdf818194e3a8c32 at commit index 1839
raft2021/11/04 22:25:56 INFO: 8e9e05c52164694d switched to configuration voters=()
raft2021/11/04 22:25:56 INFO: 8e9e05c52164694d became follower at term 17
raft2021/11/04 22:25:56 INFO: newRaft 8e9e05c52164694d [peers: [], term: 17, commit: 1839, applied: 0, lastindex: 1839, lastterm: 17]
2021-11-04 22:25:56.547839 W | auth: simple token is not cryptographically signed
2021-11-04 22:25:56.573956 I | etcdserver: starting server... [version: 3.4.15, cluster version: to_be_decided]
2021-11-04 22:25:56.580742 I | embed: listening for peers on 127.0.0.1:2380
raft2021/11/04 22:25:56 INFO: 8e9e05c52164694d switched to configuration voters=(10276657743932975437)
2021-11-04 22:25:56.582873 I | etcdserver/membership: added member 8e9e05c52164694d [http://localhost:2380] to cluster cdf818194e3a8c32
2021-11-04 22:25:56.583346 N | etcdserver/membership: set the initial cluster version to 3.4
2021-11-04 22:25:56.583568 I | etcdserver/api: enabled capabilities for version 3.4
raft2021/11/04 22:26:02 INFO: 8e9e05c52164694d is starting a new election at term 17
raft2021/11/04 22:26:02 INFO: 8e9e05c52164694d became candidate at term 18
raft2021/11/04 22:26:02 INFO: 8e9e05c52164694d received MsgVoteResp from 8e9e05c52164694d at term 18
raft2021/11/04 22:26:02 INFO: 8e9e05c52164694d became leader at term 18
raft2021/11/04 22:26:02 INFO: raft.node: 8e9e05c52164694d elected leader 8e9e05c52164694d at term 18
2021-11-04 22:26:02.051592 I | etcdserver: published {Name:default ClientURLs:[http://localhost:2379]} to cluster cdf818194e3a8c32
2021-11-04 22:26:02.052775 I | embed: ready to serve client requests
2021-11-04 22:26:02.059541 N | embed: serving insecure client requests on 127.0.0.1:2379, this is strongly discouraged!
2021/11/04 22:26:02 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: Get "https://127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=15m0s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connection refused
2021/11/04 22:26:04 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: the server is currently unable to handle the request
2021/11/04 22:26:16 [INFO] Running in single server mode, will not peer connections
2021-11-04 22:26:17.724466 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/apiextensions.k8s.io/customresourcedefinitions/\" range_end:\"/registry/apiextensions.k8s.io/customresourcedefinitions0\" " with result "range_response_count:92 size:445717" took too long (109.807669ms) to execute
2021/11/04 22:26:18 [INFO] Applying CRD features.management.cattle.io
2021/11/04 22:26:22 [INFO] Applying CRD navlinks.ui.cattle.io
2021/11/04 22:26:22 [INFO] Applying CRD clusters.management.cattle.io
2021/11/04 22:26:22 [INFO] Applying CRD apiservices.management.cattle.io
2021/11/04 22:26:23 [INFO] Applying CRD clusterregistrationtokens.management.cattle.io
2021/11/04 22:26:23 [INFO] Applying CRD settings.management.cattle.io
2021/11/04 22:26:24 [INFO] Applying CRD preferences.management.cattle.io
2021/11/04 22:26:24 [INFO] Applying CRD features.management.cattle.io
2021/11/04 22:26:25 [INFO] Applying CRD clusterrepos.catalog.cattle.io
2021/11/04 22:26:26 [INFO] Applying CRD operations.catalog.cattle.io
2021/11/04 22:26:31 [INFO] Applying CRD apps.catalog.cattle.io
2021-11-04 22:26:33.250474 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/apiextensions.k8s.io/customresourcedefinitions/\" range_end:\"/registry/apiextensions.k8s.io/customresourcedefinitions0\" " with result "range_response_count:92 size:445717" took too long (139.120063ms) to execute
2021/11/04 22:26:45 [INFO] Applying CRD fleetworkspaces.management.cattle.io
2021-11-04 22:26:47.449199 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/apiextensions.k8s.io/customresourcedefinitions/\" range_end:\"/registry/apiextensions.k8s.io/customresourcedefinitions0\" " with result "range_response_count:92 size:445717" took too long (321.346575ms) to execute
2021-11-04 22:26:52.656294 W | etcdserver: request "header:<ID:7587858304790119201 > txn:<compare:<target:MOD key:\"/registry/configmaps/kube-system/k3s\" mod_revision:1632 > success:<request_put:<key:\"/registry/configmaps/kube-system/k3s\" value_size:456 >> failure:<request_range:<key:\"/registry/configmaps/kube-system/k3s\" > >>" with result "size:16" took too long (107.766444ms) to execute
2021-11-04 22:27:03.165794 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/configmaps/kube-system/k3s\" " with result "range_response_count:1 size:515" took too long (138.87999ms) to execute
2021-11-04 22:27:03.182578 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/serviceaccounts/\" range_end:\"/registry/serviceaccounts0\" " with result "range_response_count:36 size:10156" took too long (196.135777ms) to execute
2021-11-04 22:27:21.345406 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/flowschemas/exempt\" " with result "range_response_count:1 size:879" took too long (241.774296ms) to execute
2021-11-04 22:27:21.633929 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/namespaces/kube-system\" " with result "range_response_count:1 size:340" took too long (248.96888ms) to execute
2021-11-04 22:27:30.019952 W | etcdserver: read-only range request "key:\"/registry/rolebindings/\" range_end:\"/registry/rolebindings0\" count_only:true " with result "range_response_count:0 size:7" took too long (102.695372ms) to execute
```

When I install rancher on my laptop everything is normal but when I try on my VPS this error appeared
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue with the `rancher/rancher:latest` image as well. This works for me though `rancher/rancher:v2.4-head`

```
docker pull rancher/rancher:v2.4-head
```